# Webkit browser doesn't fill up div

Tags: html, css, webkit

My code:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div style="position: relative; border:1px black solid; background-color:#00a2e8; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px; width: 1px; height: 1px">
      <table border="1" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <tr><td style="vertical-align: middle">abc</td></tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox, it displays fine, the table filling up the entire div, having the table contents vertially centered.

If I display it on Webkit-based browser, the table doesn't fill the entire div, causing the label to be vertically aligned to the top. How do I make the table expand to the whole div on Webkit-based browser?

More specifically, I am interested in Android browser.

Comment: There is no `vertical-align: center` - there is `middle` though

Comment: @sachleen You were right, I edited the code. However, that is not the problem I am experiencing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your situation, I would normally use `position:absolute;height:100%;` for the inner element. But that didn't work for a table, so I used `display:block` to make it display like a regular DIV. Seems to work well.

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fCDc/1/)

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div style="border:1px black solid; background-color:#00a2e8; min-width:100px; min-height:100px;height:100px;width:100px;">
      <table style="display:block;border:1px solid red;height:100%;">
          <tr><td style="vertical-align: center;">abc sdfs dfs df sdf sd fsd fsd fsdf sds dfs df </td></tr>

      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: That doesn't work. On the browser, the table overflows the div and spans the entire page. If I set the size of table to 1px width and height, then the table stops spanning.

Comment: Please note that specifically I am interested in Android browser. I am not sure if there are differences between various webkit-based browsers.

Comment: @Too late night for me now. The problem was that the width didn't match min-width. No need to set it smaller...

Answer (score 1):

By setting `td` **height** you can get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/d7kfR/

**Is it what you need?**

Comment: I would rather avoid setting absolute sizes. The table width and height are minimally 100px, but they could be more.